# Скорость выполнения инструкций.

Tags: delphi, ассемблер, оптимизация

Во сколько раз медленнее процессор выполняет переход к произвольной инструкции в сравнении с обычным переходом к следующей инструкции?

---

Насколько я знаю, при написании программ (как на языках высокого, так и на языках низкого уровня) нужно стараться избегать как условных, так и безусловных переходов (goto и if .. then ..). Так вот, во сколько раз быстрее будут выполнятся две пеоследовательные иструкции типа

```
mov AX,$5435;
mov LX, AX;
```

в сравнении с

```
m1:
...
cmp bx, n; 
jne m1;
```

(Не судите за ошибки, если таковые имеются, с ассемблером почти не знаком).

---

Дело в том, что я пишу программу на delphi, состоящюю из 2-ух циклов с  более 1000 интераций каждая. Вообще-то эти два цикла можно было бы объеденить в один, но код очень громоздкий, и писал я его давно(придётся ещё в нём разбираться), и тогда бы интераций было бы в 2 раза меньше. Поэтому я задал этот вопрос, чтобы убедиться в целесообразности переписывания моего кода.

Comment: В принципе вопрос интересный и в общем случае достаточно сложный, но к описанной задаче с delphi отношения не имеет. 

@ололо, как ни сделаете, все будет хорошо. Главное, чтобы было **правильно для всех входных данных и понятно другим программистам**.

Comment: Подскажите,как в комментарии добавить код?

Comment: Почему не имеет? 
Попробую объяснить без кода. Например есть 2 цикла. В конце каждого из них при компиляции с delphi стоит иструкция условного перехода - если счётчик цикла меньше или равен общему чиислу требуемых интераций заданных вначале, вернуться на начло цикла. 2 цикла - 2 условных перехода, 1 цикл - 1 условный переход. Разве не очевидно, что первое (при 2-ух циклах) медленнее? Впрос, во-сколько раз

Comment: Код в комментарии

    это код в комментарии 

Два раза <Enter> 4 пробела текст кода два <Enter>. Так (или почти так), пробуйте.

Comment: @ололо, фак читайте. пустая строка до кода, четыре пробела перед каждой строкой кода, пустая строка после кода. работает как для ответов, так и для комментариев.

Comment: Нужно просто стараться избегать безусловных "прыжков". Для дельфи - это GOTO, для ASM - JMP. Они являются плохим тоном, плохим стилем программирования, да и к тому же запутывают.

Comment: Но я говорю не про стиль, и не про принятые соглашения между программистами,  а про эффективность и скорость. В моей программе КРАЙНЕ ВАЖНА  скорость работы.

Comment: мне одному глаз режут "интерации"? 

По теме, циклы вложенные? Скорее всего да (раз безусловный переход требуется) и хоть какое направление задачи, может кто-то подскажет как по умному можно соптимизировать?

Comment: Нет. Циклы независимы, но работают с одним и тем же массивом. А переход условный (раз цикл со счётчиком for i:=1 to b do)

Comment: @ололо, Вы забыли о предсказании переходов и  предвыборке команд и данных в современных CPU, а также об ограничениях размера буферов CPU, используемых для этого. 

Тут надо смотреть очень конкретно на модель CPU, исполняемый код и данные. И лучше консультироваться, скажем, с Инженерами Intel.

Comment: Ну 1000 итераций это мало (хотя конечно если вы не в каждый элемент по файлу загружаете)

Comment: Соглашаюсь с avp

Comment: > Нужно просто стараться избегать безусловных "прыжков". Для дельфи - это GOTO, для ASM - JMP. Они являются плохим тоном, плохим стилем программирования, да и к тому же запутывают.

Для ЯВУ верно, для ассемблера неверно. В общем случае на ассемблере цикл состоит из одного условного и одного безусловного перехода, так что полностью "избежать" JMP невозможно. Нужно избегать [спагетти-кода](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code), а не JMP.

Comment: Мало что понятно, кроме факта преждевременной оптимизации. Надо брать профайлер и искать узкие места (которые наверняка далеко не в ветвлениях двоичного кода).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы, мне кажется, подходите к оптимизации не с той стороны.

Честно говоря - "но код очень громоздкий" код в циклк - это уже не есть гуд. Есть правило, что если действие **можно** сделать вне цикла - его **нужно** сделать вне цикла.

Во-вторых. Если бы ваш цикл делал миллиард повторений - тогда об этом уже было бы смысл думать. Но у вас 1000 повторений - забудьте и забейте. В *самом пессимистичном прогнозе* оно будет работать на процессоре с не менее 500 миллионов тактов/сек. На сравнение регистра с памятью нужно 2 такта насколько помню...

Плюс на фоне "громоздкого" цикла - плюс цмп, минус цмп. Да и откуда вы знаете, в какой вид утрамбует это дельфя при компиляции))

Answer (score -1):

Хотите невероятной производительности? Тогда извините, но не ту IDE вы выбрали. Delphi пихает в исполняемый файл очень много лишнего, и сильно его нагружает, тем самым уменьшает производительность и в значительной степени увеличивает его размер.

Хотите производительности именно в Delphi? Окай. Пишите программы используя ТОЛЬКО функции WinApi, не используя VCL. Тогда да, исполняемый файл даст фору по скорости exe'шникам откомпилированным в любой другой IDE, и будет весить в несколько раз меньше.

> нужно стараться избегать как условных, так и безусловных переходов (goto и if .. then ..)

Ну goto это я еще понимаю, но чем вам условный оператор не угодил? Он вообще-то помогает уменьшить объем кода, делая метаморфные процедуры/функции.

> можно было бы объеденить в один, но код очень громоздкий

В любом случае рефакторинг в студию

PS. 1000 итераций сами по себе ерунда. Все зависит от того, что в них выполняется. Так что вы бы хоть примерно описали то, что вы делаете, если конечно хотите более-менее внятный ответ.

Comment: "Хотите производительности именно в Delphi? Окай. Пишите программы используя ТОЛЬКО функции WinApi, не используя VCL. "

Для студенческих курсовых может и сойдёт, в реальной жизни лучше так не делать.

Comment: @teanЫЧ, @alexlz, вы что обсуждаете ? Вопрос был:

    Во сколько раз медленнее процессор выполняет переход к произвольной инструкции в сравнении с обычным переходом к следующей инструкции?

Все остальное автор неизвестно для чего добавил.

Comment: @avp так вопрос-то наподобие вопроса о часах. Правильный ответ: "хрен его знает"